# Конструкция генератора шума

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

> digital image processing  (Numpy)
>
> Конструкция генератора шума:
> Типы шума характеризуются их распределением:
> 1.1 Гауссов Шум
> 1.2 Реликтовый шум
> 1.3 Гамма-шум
> 1.4 Экспоненциальный шум
> 1.5 Равномерный шум
> 1,6 Кг Соли И Перца
> Для каждого типа шума нужно написать функцию, которая получает переменные a, b и размер изображения. Функция должна возвращать изображение с шумом. Положение компонентов шума на изображении является случайным, а распределение интенсивности различных пикселей определяется функцией плотности типа шума и переменными a, b.
> Нужно проверить решение по гистограмме результата 50*50

Comment: Stackoverflow - это не то место где вам сделают домашнее задание. Stackoverflow - это место где вам ответят на вопросы

Comment: мне не нужно как домашнее задание . Меня интересует  как мне реализовать .

Comment: я хочу увидеть как в коде сделать мне (один хотя бы)

Comment: Ну так и задавайте свой вопрос. Еще очень желательно показать то, что вы уже сделали.

Comment: Шумы генерируются элементарно.

Comment: мне нужно реализовать без import cv2
 а через библиотеку matplotlib

Comment: а пока у меня есть только этот вариант

Comment: '
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import numpy as np

import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Test_pattern.tif')

# Generate Gaussian noise

gauss = np.random.normal(0,1,img.size)

gauss = gauss.reshape(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],img.shape[2]).astype('uint8')

# Add the Gaussian noise to the image

img_gauss = cv2.add(img,gauss)

# Display the image

cv2.imshow('a',img_gauss)

cv2.waitKey(0)
'

Answer (score 1):

Генерация шумов производиться элементарно.

1.Если нужный вам закон распределения присутствует в библиотеке scipy.stats, используется соответствующий объект из этой библиотеки.
Параметры генератора отличаются для каждого из распределений и
описаны в документации. Все описанные вами "шумы" в этой б-ке есть
(ну, кроме 1.6).

2.Если желаете пользоваться библиотекой numpy.random, а в ней (вдруг) не окажется нужного вам распределения, то генерация состоит
из двух подшагов -  на первом генерируете равномерное распределение,
а на втором с помощью известной вам функции плотности распределения
генерируете из полученного равномерного набора нужный вам закон.
Если это вам непонятно -  ищем в интернете (информации куча) или  на
крайний случай (если вдруг что-то там останется непонятным)- постим
конкретно этот вопрос.

3.Сгенерированные наборы данных добавляются к матричному представлению
вашего изображения. Поскольку от вас просят зашумить
интенсивность - работаете с форматом данных, в которых есть такое
представление. Если положение выбирается случайно - то используете
функцию random.choice или numpy.random.choice.

4.Гистограмма объекта строиться -  например -  методом
matplotlib.pyplot.hist().

Вот такая вот "конструкция" генератора шума, как вы и спрашивали.

Comment: спасибо . постараюсь по инструкции сделать

Comment: Новичку - для информации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers